# C# appending string from variable inside double quotes

Tags: c#

Hi I have the following line:

```
var table = @"<table id=""table_id"" class=""display"">
```

which is building a table and continues on the next line but I'm just trying to append a string at the end of table_id :

```
var table = @"<table id=""table_id" + instance + """ class=""display"">
```

so the final output (if instance = 1234) should be:

```
<table id="table_id1234" class="display">
```

But I think the quotes are throwing it off. Any suggestions on how t achieve the last line?

Thanks

Comment: I think I'm using 4.0

Comment: The escape "quotes" should be `\"`, not `""`

Comment: @Prisoner With @ strings, backslashes are literal, so double quotes are escaped by pairing them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method placeholder is enough to concatenate `instance` without cutting through quote signs (`{0}` is the placeholder):

```
var table = string.Format(@"<table id=""table_id{0}"" class=""display"">", instance);
```

Or you can use escape sequence `\"` for escaping quotes without string literal:

```
var table = "<table id=\"table_id" + instance + "\" class=\"display\">"
```

Result:

```
<table id="table_id1234" class="display">
```

Demo: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7TZrPl)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use escape character for double quote(`\"`) using this code:

```
var id = "1234";
var table = "<table id=\"table_id" + id + "\" class=\"display\">";
```

Here is an online tool for converting string to escape/unescape:

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

So you can copy the result and place your variables.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea and newest idea for this situation is $ sign before your text and with this sign you dont need to extra sign in your string

example

```
vat table = $"<table id='table_id{instance}' class='display'">
```

Comment: This feature is available in C# 6 and later versions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings. ZeeFer is using C#4.0

Comment: @JericCruz he didn't say anything about the version of his C#

Comment: @JericCruz you are super herooooo

Answer (score 0):

@ is used  to escape double quotes from one string but in your example, you are actually concatenating three different strings, soyou should escape the third string as well like this:

```
var table = @"<table id=""table_id" + instance + @" "" class=""display"" >";
```

Alternatively, you could also use the [StringBuilder](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP8onC9NXWAhXrDZoKHWATCG8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.text.stringbuilder(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AOvVaw1jD4owLQAvwUCMP5rd4SI1) class which is more memory efficient and might make your strings easier to read.